# Specialize struct template depending on signed-ness of char

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a function `template<typename T> void frobnicate()` that does stuff. I need T to be one of a few select types, and I need some information about those types. I do this by providing traits:

```
template<typename T_Raw>
struct FrobnicationTraits
{
        static constexpr bool isValidFrobnicationType = false;
};

template<>
struct FrobnicationTraits<unsigned char>
{
        static constexpr bool isValidFrobnicationType = true;
        static constexpr bool isUnsigned = true;
        static constexpr unsigned char minValue = 0;
        static constexpr unsigned char maxValue = 255;
        //Elided in each specialization: some other values that are needed by frobnicate()
};

template<>
struct FrobnicationTraits<signed char>
{
        static constexpr bool isValidFrobnicationType = true;
        static constexpr bool isUnsigned = false;
        static constexpr signed char minValue = -128;
        static constexpr signed char maxValue =  127;
};

//Elided: versions for unsigned short and signed short
```

And then:

```
template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<FrobnicationTraits<T>::isValidFrobnicationType>::type>
void frobnicate()
{
    using Traits = FrobnicationTraits<T>;
    auto promotedMinValue = +Traits::minValue;
    auto promotedMaxValue = +Traits::maxValue;
    std::cout << "Frobnicating with " << (Traits::isUnsigned ? "unsigned" : "  signed") << " type of size " << sizeof(T) <<" between " << promotedMinValue << " and " << promotedMaxValue << std::endl;
    //...
}
```

This works fine for these calls:

```
int main()
{
    frobnicate<unsigned char>();  // Prints "Frobnicating with unsigned type of size 1 between 0 and 255"
    frobnicate<  signed char>();  // Prints "Frobnicating with   signed type of size 1 between -128 and 127"
    frobnicate<unsigned short>(); // Prints "Frobnicating with unsigned type of size 2 between 0 and 65535"
    frobnicate<  signed short>(); // Prints "Frobnicating with   signed type of size 2 between -32768 and 32767"
    //frobnicate<unsigned int>(); // Correctly fails to compile, because the enable_if is not satisfied, since FrobnicationTraits<unsigned int> uses the default FrobnicationTraits where isValidFrobnicationType is false
    return 0;
}
```

But now I want to be able to correctly `frobnicate<char>()`.
`char` is implementation-defined to be signed or unsigned, but it's always considered to be a different type than `unsigned char` and `signed char`. So simply calling `frobnicate<char>()` fails to compile, because it won't pick any of the specialized FrobnicationTraits.
I can add one specialization manually:

```
template<>
struct FrobnicationTraits<char>
{
        static constexpr bool isValidFrobnicationType = true;
        static constexpr bool isUnsigned = true;
        static constexpr char minValue = 0;
        static constexpr char maxValue = 255;
};
```

But I can't know ahead of time whether this is the correct one. In fact, I happened to pick the wrong values, so this prints "Frobnicating with unsigned type of size 1 between 0 and -1".

I would like to effectively do this:

```
template<> // I don't know where to put the `std::enable_if<>` here, but use this if char is unsigned
struct FrobnicationTraits<char>
{
        static constexpr bool isValidFrobnicationType = true;
        static constexpr bool isUnsigned = true;
        static constexpr char minValue = 0;
        static constexpr char maxValue = 255;
};

template<> // I don't know where to put the `std::enable_if<>` here, but use this if char is signed
struct FrobnicationTraits<char>
{
        static constexpr bool isValidFrobnicationType = true;
        static constexpr bool isUnsigned = false;
        static constexpr char minValue = -128;
        static constexpr char maxValue =  127;
};
```

Ideally the solution should not use the preprocessor.

Answer (score 6):

There is [`std::is_signed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed) that can tell you wether `char` is signed or not. If you need not distinguish between `char` and `signed char` / `unsigned char` you can reuse the traits by inheriting from either of them via [std::conditional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
template<>
struct FrobnicationTraits<char> : FrobnicationTraits<
                                      std::conditional_t<         
                                          std::is_signed_v<char>, 
                                          signed char,
                                          unsigned char
                                      >
                                  >
{};
```

Perhaps use a helper:

```
using signed_or_unsigned_char = std::conditional_t<std::is_signed_v<char>,signed char, unsigned char>;
```

then inherit `FrobnicationTraits<char>` from `FrobnicationTraits<signed_or_unsigned_char>`.

PS: Note that some of your traits functionality is already covered by [`std::numerical_limits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits). If you use `std::is_signed` directly, all you actually need in the trait is `isValidFrobnicationType`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use templates to reduce repetitive code, and automatically calculate `isUnsigned`, `minValue` and `maxValue` through [`std::numerical_limits<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)

```
#include <limits>

template<class T>
constexpr inline bool isValidFrobnicationType = false;
// specialization for valid types
template<>
constexpr inline bool isValidFrobnicationType<signed char> = true;
// ...

template<typename T, bool = isValidFrobnicationType<T>>
struct FrobnicationTraits;

template<typename T>
struct FrobnicationTraits<T, false> {
  static constexpr bool isValidFrobnicationType = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct FrobnicationTraits<T, true> {
  static constexpr bool isValidFrobnicationType = true;
  static constexpr bool isUnsigned = !std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed;
  static constexpr auto minValue =    std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
  static constexpr auto maxValue =    std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ec57a7hcv)